# How does Ubuntu 22.04 LTS handle LUKS2 decryption of root partition on boot?

Tags: boot, grub2, luks

I am trying to figure out how to add a LUKS2 encrypted Arch and a LUKS2 encrypted Ubuntu on different drives into my GRUB2 boot entries. In my Arch installation, I got GRUB to decrypt my LUKS-root partition by appending `cryptdisk=UUID=<my-UUID>:cryptroot root=/dev/mapper/cryptroot` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub`. However, in my Ubuntu install, this is neither present in `/etc/default/grub` nor in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. How, and when, is LUKS decryption handled by Ubuntu 22.04?